# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(\sin \frac{\pi + x}{3}) + f(\cos \frac{\pi + x}{3})}{e^x -1} = 1$, Prove that $f(x_i)=0$ for some $x_i\in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that:
> $$
> \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(\sin \frac{\pi + x}{3}) + f(\cos \frac{\pi + x}{3})}{e^x -1} = 1
> $$
> Prove that there is an $x_i \in [0,1]$ that $f(x_i)= 0.$

I know that it means that the sum of function values with trigonometric functions behave like $e^x -1$ near $0$ and $e^x - 1$ near $0$ behaves like $x$, but what do I do with those trig functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the limit the denominator is zero thus the numerator must be zero otherwise the limit won't exist so $ f\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) + f\left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) = 0 $ And as $[0,1]$ is complete and $f$ is continuous the result follows from IVT

Comment: In IVT the set must be complete or it should have the lub-glb property